# Lock my android application in reversed Landscape mode

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, layout

I can already lock the android application in landscape mode from the manifest file of android. But we use a custom tablet built solely for our company and due to the manufacturing defect, the laptop orientation is reversed.

Is there any way I can lock the application in reverse landscape mode??

Comment: Found the solution you can ignore this post

Comment: You should post your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-orientation-locker](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-orientation-locker) which allows us to lock the orientation of device in our desired way using the following methods,

> lockToPortrait()
>   lockToLandscape()
>   lockToLandscapeLeft() this will lock to camera left home button right
>   lockToLandscapeRight() this will lock to camera right home button left